# Combine Laravel ORM with() and select() methods

Tags: php, laravel, activerecord, laravel-5, orm

I have Player and Payment models. in payments table there is "player_id" column. 
I want to select specific attributes of Player + Payment relation. In other words I want to combine this 2 queries.

```
 1. User::where(/* some condition */)->with('payment')->get();
 2. User::where(/* some condition */)->select([/* some attributes */])->get();
```

But if I try

```
User::where(/* some condition */)->select([/* some attributes */])->with('payment')->get();
```

returned model's relations array is empty.

Comment: And if you add in select array also `payment.*` ?

Comment: Add your select after the `with` scope and add payment attribute wildcard or desired field names to the select to fetch it's fields.

Comment: you can pass the select condition in your `get(['id', ...])`. Can you please print your generated query with `dd(User::where()...->toSql())`? Also please print your whole query with the select attributes. I think you don't include the user.id so it's impossible for the query to load the relationship to the payment

Comment: none of suggested ones works. seems laravel executes 2 separate queries for User and Payment and if I add payment.* it triggers error because of payment.*.

Comment: do you add the **hasMany** relations in **User** model?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this -

```
`User::where(/* some condition */)->select([/* some attributes of user */])->with(['payment' => function ($q) {
    return $q->select(/* some attributes payment */)
}])->get();`
```

Comment: This solution should work if you are using correctly. Can you please send me complete table structure and relation and what exactly you tried?.

Answer (score 0):

A bit tricky, but should works

```
User::where(/* some condition */)->select([/* some attributes */])->get()->load('payment');
```